# Pandas: How to calculate turnover rate?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to calculate the turnover rate of a group of persons using Pandas. The size of the group may change, but I want to know the percentage of people that left each year.

Better explain with an example. Here is my sample data:

```
  teachers  year
0     John  2007
1     Paul  2007
2     Mary  2007

3     John  2008
4     Paul  2008
5     Abel  2008
6     Watt  2008

7     John  2009
8     Mary  2009
```

I'd like to arrive in this dataset:

```
year turnover 
2008 .33333 
2009 .75
```

In the first year, Mary left, in the second year Paul, Abel and Watt left. It would have some kind of bias: if the group is shrinking, the turnover rate would be bigger.

Comment: If Mary leaves in 2010, but Karl joins that same year, is the turnover rate 0.0 or 0.5?

Comment: @pshep123: It always based in the number of people from the past year that stays in the current year. So John would stay from 2009, and the turnover rate is 0.5. He is probably an angry boss, since is the one that survives from the beginning :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it then be .333 for 2008? There were 3 people in 2007 and 2 of them remained.

Comment: @jdehsa: sure! your are right. I simplified my first example and forgot to edit it. I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Plan**

- I'm going to set the index with `'year'` and `'teachers'`, so I `assign` a dummy variable of `x=1` ahead of time.
- I want to have `'year'` as my index, so I `unstack` to put `'teachers'` in the columns.  I use the `fill_value=0` option to fill in zeros where teachers weren't there for a particular year.
- Using `diff` and checking if equal to -1 identifies a turnover event.  `sum(1)` sums up all turnover events.
- `d1.sum(1).shift()` counts all teachers from prior year.
- divide to get turnover.

---

```
d1 = pd.Series(1, [df.year, df.teachers]).unstack(fill_value=0)
d1.diff().eq(-1).sum(1).div(d1.sum(1).shift(), 0).dropna()

year
2008    0.333333
2009    0.750000
dtype: float64
```

---

As pointed out by @jrjc in the comments, my first line is a `crosstab`.  with that in mind, we can reduce the code to:

```
d1 = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.teachers)
d1.diff().eq(-1).sum(1).div(d1.sum(1).shift(), 0).dropna()
```

---

***one line using `pipe`***

```
pd.crosstab(df.year, df.teachers).pipe(
    lambda c: c.diff().eq(-1).sum(1).div(c.sum(1).shift(),0).dropna()
)
```

Comment: your `d1` is just a crosstab: `d1 = pd.crosstab(df.year, df.teachers)`. The next line is nice though!

Comment: @jrjc You are right of course... oddly enough, my way is quicker under certain scenarios.  However, speed was not my focus and `crosstab` is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table(StringIO(
"""  teachers  year
0     John  2007
1     Paul  2007
2     Mary  2007
3     John  2008
4     Paul  2008
5     Abel  2008
6     Watt  2008
7     John  2009
8     Mary  2009"""
), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)

data['presence'] = 1
teacher_presence = data.groupby(['teachers', 'year']).count().unstack(1).fillna(0)
teacher_presence.columns = teacher_presence.columns.droplevel(0)

teacher_remain = teacher_presence.iloc[:, 1:] * teacher_presence.iloc[:, :-1].values
turnover = 1 - teacher_remain.sum() / teacher_presence.iloc[:, :-1].sum().values
turnover.name = 'turnover'

print(turnover)
```

Result:

```
year
2008    0.333333
2009    0.750000
Name: turnover, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can convert teachers to `set` after grouping, then perform set operations.

```
In [72]: t = df.groupby('year')['teachers'].apply(lambda x: set(x.values.tolist()))

In [73]: t
Out[73]:
year
2007          {John, Paul, Mary}
2008    {John, Abel, Paul, Watt}
2009                {John, Mary}
Name: teachers, dtype: object

In [76]: t.combine(t.shift(), lambda a, b: len(b-a) / len(b) if isinstance(b, set) else np.nan).dropna()
Out[76]:
year
2008    0.333333
2009        0.75
Name: teachers, dtype: object
```